# Configuring qtbase fails with an error: "Could not find qmake spec ''."

Tags: qt

I am trying to cross-compile qtbase-everywhere-5.11.0 for the Raspberry Pi 3 and configure phase exits after the qmake compilation with the error given below:

```
make: Nothing to be done for 'first'.
Could not find qmake spec ''.
Error processing project file: /work/qtbase-everywhere-src-5.11.0
```

I do it inside a docker container. Here is the `Dockerfile`

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

COPY sources.list /etc/apt/

RUN apt update -q -yy && \
    apt upgrade -q -yy && \
    apt install -q -yy aptitude curl

RUN dpkg --add-architecture armhf

RUN apt install -q -yy --allow-downgrades \
        build-essential \
        linux-libc-dev:armhf=4.15.0-20.21 linux-libc-dev:amd64=4.15.0-20.21 \
        crossbuild-essential-armhf \
        libncurses5:amd64=6.1-1ubuntu1 \
        libncursesw5:amd64=6.1-1ubuntu1 \
        libtinfo5:amd64=6.1-1ubuntu1 \
        libgles2-mesa-dev:armhf \
        libpcre3-dev:armhf \
        libasound2-dev:armhf \
        libasound2-data=1.1.3-5
```

and the `configure` arguments

```
configure \
     -device linux-rasp-pi3-g++ \
     -examplesdir /usr/lib/qt/examples \
     -headerdir /usr/include/qt5 \
     -no-rpath \
     -nomake tests \
     -plugindir /usr/lib/qt/plugins \
     -prefix /usr \
     -v \
     -confirm-license \
     -eglfs \
     -no-cups \
     -no-iconv \
     -no-kms \
     -no-pch \
     -no-use-gold-linker \
     -no-xcb \
     -no-sql-sqlite \
     -no-sql-mysql \
     -no-sql-psql \
     -no-sql-tds \
     -no-sql-odbc \
     -no-linuxfb \
     -no-widgets \
     -opengl es2 \
     -opensource \
     -release \
     -shared \
     -system-zlib \
     -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-
```

I realized that configuring it with default parameters doesn't work either. Running just `./configure -v` inside a source directory gives the same error.

I found that it doesn't happen when I am building using `dockcross/linux-armhf7` based docker image.

Comment: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-64490 Funny, they literally claim this is not a bug but a feature, which you can presumably disable by  -no-feature-statx which actually has not effect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is caused by the libseccomp version that ships with Ubuntu 18.04 (v2.3.1) not being recent enough to know the `statx` syscall, so it cannot be whitelisted (v2.3.3 would be required for that, which will be shipped with the next Ubuntu version). Qt 5.10 uses this syscall in its build process, though.

As a temporary workaround, you can add `--security-opt seccomp:unconfined` to your docker command line, but you should be aware of the security implications and only use this on trusted docker containers. Alternatively, you can of course try upgrading the `libseccomp2` package.

Comment: Do you mean libseccomp on the host?

Comment: Yes, all software and software versions mentioned in my post refer to the host that runs Docker.

Comment: I see. My problem: I want to build Qt on cloud.docker.com and run into this problem :(